# Typescript, D3 and powerBI: How do i get typescript to talk to D3 v4?

Tags: typescript, powerbi, d3.js

I'm trying to get D3 working in powerBI so I can create custom visuals. I come to it from the D3 end of things, and am not familiar with typescript, powerBI, or even terminal app (am on a mac).

I've got D3 V3 working using this: https://github.com/Svjard/d3-typescript. I put the d3.d.ts file into the .tmp/precompile/src folder and referenced the file from visual.ts. Initially I included data.ts and tsconfig.json but I've found these aren't needed.

But I'd like to use D3 V4. There's a handler for D3 V4 thanks to definitely typed: https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped. I ran `npm install @types/d3-selection --save` and took the index.d.ts file, put it in the .tmp/precompile/src folder and re-referenced visual.js but no joy. I renamed it d3.d.ts in case that helped: nope. I used the definitelyTyped package.json in place of the powerBI-generated one but that didn't help either (and I suspect misunderstands what the file is for!).

I get an error from the terminal app:
[image: error on typescript-d3 compile]

The code looks quite different. This is a snip of the (v3) file that works:

```
interface ID3Selectors {
    select: (selector: string) => ID3Selection;
    selectAll: (selector: string) => ID3Selection;
}

interface ID3Base extends ID3Selectors {
```

And here's a snip of the other file that doesn't work:

```
export type BaseType = Element | EnterElement | Window;

/**
 * A helper interface which covers arguments like NodeListOf<T> or HTMLCollectionOf<T>
 * argument types
 */
export interface ArrayLike<T> {
    length: number;
    item(index: number): T;
    [index: number]: T;
}
```

Does anyone know how I get typescript to talk to D3 V4?

thanks...

Emma

---

**EDIT 31 October 2016**
Thanks for answers. When I ran `tsc -v` in the CLI it said 2.0.6.

I've improved my situation but not got to V4. In case of use, this is what I've done and what's worked. There seemed to be three suggested methods:

(1) Following instructions here didn't work for me: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/Tutorial/ExternalLibraries.md

(2) Following instructions here did work: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/Tutorial/Typings.md

This involved using CLI and npm to install typings. Then adding typings to project folder, again with instructions from Typings.md link above. This created a folder called 'typings'. I updated tsconfig to load index.d.ts. I removed the reference to d3.d.ts from visuals.js.

The improvement is significant. This index.d.ts is version 3 like the last file I used, d3.d.ts. However unlike the last link it seems to support click events and probably other things I have yet to discover.

(3) I followed Tom W's instructions (for which thanks) and now have a d3-selection folder as well as a @types d3-selection folder. However, I couldn't get the import command to work in my visuals.ts file. I tried in various locations, within and outside of functions. i also copied the d3-selection folder from node_modules (not sure if i was meant to!).

[image: Atom software showing visual.ts]

---

**EDIT 1 November 2016.** Thanks again for help. I'm no further forward though. One of my key confusions is why both external/d3.v4.js and a npm installation are needed. Surely it's one or the other?

**(1) The external/d3.v4.js method**
@Jan - have you got D3 v4 working in power BI? If so what was the exact npm code you ran and what else did you do? My test code is like so (var x = d3.scaleLinear();) - if you can compile successfully with this code please tell me how you did it!

[image: Atom showing visual.ts file with d3 v4 code]

I've included d3.v4.js into a folder called external and referenced it in tsconfig.json. This feels right. But power BI compilation within terminal fails, with the error message: Cannot find name 'd3'. Is there some [other command needed](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/issues/98)?

**(2) Mixing in the npm approach**
@Tom, thanks and I followed your instructions. Here's my node_modules:
[image: node_modules folder]

Confusingly, `npm install @types/d3 --save-dev` created a new node_modules folder within an existing one. Once you've installed with npm, do you copy or move the folder (e.g. into the power bi project root)? I don't see how power BI can find these files.

[image: @types folder within node_modules]

I put the d3.v4.js file into external/ and referenced it with a reference link and types attribute set to d3. The compiler said: "invalid reference directive". I changed types to path and tried to set the path to external/d3.v4.js but powerBI seems hard coded to look in the .tmp/precompile folder.

I've got the d3 file loaded fine, though, removing the reference link and using powerBI's tsconfig.json instead. But I'm back to where I was. The file loads but d3 is not a recognised name.

It sounds as though if I wait till Microsoft has done their thing, I'll be able to use the typings method to get to V4. But it's just so annoying. Microsoft documentation says I can use d3 pre-loaded, or load my own copy of d3, without any npm at all. I must be missing a command to make the d3 namespace recognised!

Comment: This seems pointless if your objective is to publish to powerbi.com.

Comment: Which part strikes you as pointless? To create a custom visual, I need to use D3 and I'd rather use V4 than V3.

Comment: How do you plan to publish it?  Presuming it is to powerbi.com, so you will likely have to comply with what they support.

Comment: I briefly looked over your "edit update". One fundamental question regarding your use case: Do you use (1) `import` statements to load external modules (i.e. PowerBI supports some kind of module  loading) or are you (2) using "globals" provided by external libraries like D3 in a vanilla script?

Comment: Just to clarify: Please do duplicate the installation of D3 modules, which are already included in the Standard Bundle, if you use it. E.g. if you install `d3` with `@types/d3`. Do not install `d3-select` and `@types/d3-selection` as well. For the modules already in the standard bundle, there is no need to duplicate, as the dependencies will be installed as per usual with npm. As you pointed out the key piece of information you need, is whether D3 will be used through module `import` or is loaded as a vanilla script from the `external` folder. Vanilla script = need `d3` global.

Answer (score 2):

The current definitions for D3 v4 have been completely migrated from https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-v4-definitelytyped to [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) (currently in the `types-2.0` branch). That's where they are now maintained and issues managed.

The branch publishes to the **npm @types** organization, which is the new "standard" mechanism for publishing and acquiring definition files with **TypeScript 2**.

Importantly, you will need TypeScript 2 (at least 1.9.x-dev) to use these definitions. Looking at the compiler error, I suspect you might compile with TS 1.8.x. My somewhat educated guess is based on the fact that it throws on `this`, the other errors are coincidental. The new definitions I wrote make use of `this`-typing for function contexts, which was not supported in 1.8.x.

So, setting powerBI aside for a second, say you want to install, import and use the `d3-selection` module, you would:

(1) Install the actual module `npm install d3-selection --save`

(2) Install the corresponding definition file `npm install @types/d3-selection --save` (or `--save-dev` if you are not writing a library for third party consumption)

(3) In the module, where you require d3-selection, you simply import in a standard TypeScript/ES6 manner:

```
import * as d3Selection from 'd3-selection';

let svg = d3Selection.select('svg'); // or whatever you may be up to
```

Note the following, the definitions installable from `@types/d3` correspond to the D3 v4 Standard Bundle published by Mike Bostock. (Until yesterday, the "latest" version was still the D3 v3.5.x definition.)

Alternatively, if your use-case is based on using D3 in a *vanilla script* (rather than with module imports) to get it to work with powerBI, then let me know and I can provide additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of tom (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40315607/7094192) should help you in enabling D3 v4 with Power BI custom visuals. The Power BI custom visual API documentation provides some guidance in using an external library together with your Power BI custom visual: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/Tutorial/ExternalLibraries.md. Adding a reference to `index.d.ts` in the `tsconfig.json` file should be enough.

By default Power BI injects D3 v3.5.5 to be used by custom visuals and in that case installing only the typings would be enough: https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/Tutorial/Typings.md But of course this can be changed in the future.

**UPDATE December 4th, 2016**:

Finally had some time to try it myself and I got *d3js v4* working with Power BI. I don't; believe it is the complete correct way (too many manual changes), but it works :-). There are the steps I executed:

1. I used `rollup` with an input script (`custom.d3.js`) with all the d3js modules needed (here only `d3.version`):

   ```
   export {
     version
   } from './node_modules/d3/build/package';
   ```
2. Created a `iife` version via `rollup.config.js`:

   ```
   import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
   export default {
     entry: 'custom.d3.js',
     dest: 'external/d3.js',
     format: 'iife',
     moduleName: 'd3',
     plugins: [ nodeResolve({jsnext: true}) ]
   }
   ```
3. Create custom *d3js v4* file (`d3.js`) via `rollup -c`
4. Manually edited the `d3.js` file

   - add `var d3;` at the top
   - replace all `exports` with d3
   - change the last line of the file to `})(d3 || (d3 = {}));`

These steps will create a workable js file that can be included in the output inline script Power BI can handle via adding a reference in the `tsconfig.json` file.

For the intellisense I used the new typings @tom was talking via `npm install @types/d3 --save-dev` (depending on the modules you are using). To enable the intellisense in the `visual.ts` file I added `/// <reference types="d3" />` just after the `module powerbi.extensibility.visual {` line.

The biggest drawback is of course the manual step 4, but I cannot find a way to eliminate that (yet). Maybe someone with more experience with `rollup` can help.

Thanks, JP

Comment: Thanks Jan. For other people: these instructions (https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/Tutorial/ExternalLibraries.md) didn't work for me: I included d3.v4.js in a folder called "external", referenced it from tsconfig but was not able to use d3 commands in my visual.ts file. The typings reference  (whatever a 'typing' is - https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/Tutorial/Typings.md) worked. It is only V3, but it's more comprehensive than the D3 V3 file I used in original post (which had no support for click events). Seem to need .d.ts file for D3 V4.

Comment: In going over Jan's comments and related to my question of whether you 'import' or use  a 'global' to access D3, please try the following: Include the `d3.v4.js` into your externals folders (assuming that PowerBi treats it like an vanilla script, rather than a proper module), then instead of using the `typings` instructions: use `npm install @types/d3 --save-dev` and add `/// <reference types="d3" />` to the top of the script where you use D3. This should add the "global" `d3` to your script for use, e.g. `d3.select(...)` (Again, the key question is modules v vanilla script)

Comment: Hi Emma, indeed the 'typings' reference works for the provided d3 lib which is v3.I just tried tom's way (finally had an working environment near me) and it looks like only the `npm` command is working for the v4 version.

Comment: (Sorry press enter too fast). Forgot to mention that indeed you need to add the new `d3.v4.js` file to be included in the `pbiviz` file by adding it to the external folder and include in the `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: Yes, to clarify a technical aspect: If you are using `typings` with `dt` it will pull definitions from the DefinitelyTyped `master` branch. These are the "old" D3 v3.5.x definitions. DT has another branch called `types-2.0` which is the feeder branch for npm @types. If you use @types, you get the latest available D3 v4 definitions (by module or for the Standard D3v4 bundle (i.e. @types/d3)). You can use `npm install @types/d3@3.5 --save-dev` to get the last old D3 v3.5.x definitions as well. Otherwise, the D3 standard bundle is in the major version 4 range for `@types/d3`.

Comment: P.S. When the Microsoft TypeScript team is finished with some of the ongoing tooling work. `types-2.0` will become the new `master` in DefinitelyTyped.

Comment: Jan, please share your d3.js file. I’m trying to create a line plot in d3v3 (like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040354/plot-a-line-using-d3-js-library-in-power-bi-custom-visual ), but typings for this version are wrong, so it leads me to give a try to d3v4.

Answer (score 0):

From the compiler output it looks like the typings file is invalid.

I took a quick look at the repository for V4 and it says that it was made for typoscript 2.+. I don't know wether power BI support this yet as i'm not really familiar with the software but it might be worth looking into. I'd look into this first, as the compiler 's trying to tell you that the syntax in the .d.ts file isn't even close to valid.

I took a look at typescript for power BI and it apparently uses the tsconfig.json file to determine which files to build and in which order, so that would be a good place to start looking as well. It might be that you are referencing files that have not been loaded at that point.

Good luck and if you get some new information it might be worth editing your question for some more accurate help. ;)