# Plot a line using d3.js library in Power BI custom visual

Tags: d3.js, typescript, plot, powerbi

I'm struggling with plotting a sigle line in Power BI custom visual. Reports in Power BI are written using TypeScript and d3.js v.3.0. I'm able to plot chart with axes, but the line doesn't appear. Using pure d3.js in HTML file is really easy, but it is hard to integrate it with TypeScript due to typings preservation.

While developing this code I have had several problems with typings. Code below almost works. Take a look at this snippet. Issue with typings arises, when at the bottom I delete 'any'.

[Here is link to sandbox at CodePen: https://codepen.io/SuszonyDzik/pen/aBaJJQ](https://codepen.io/SuszonyDzik/pen/aBaJJQ)

```
module powerbi.extensibility.visual {
    export class Visual implements IVisual {
        private target: HTMLElement;
        private updateCount: number;

        private svg: d3.Selection<SVGAElement>;
        private host: IVisualHost;
        private selectionManager: ISelectionManager;

        //private xAxis: d3.Selection<SVGAElement>;
        //private yAxis: d3.Selection<SVGAElement>;


        private data = [
            {date: "2011-10-01",    close: 582.13},
            {date: "2011-10-10",    close: 303.00},
            {date: "2011-10-20",    close: 103.00},
            {date: "2011-10-25",    close: 143.00},
        ]

        static Config = {
            xScalePadding: 0.1,
            solidOpacity: 1,
            transparentOpacity: 0.5,
            xAxisFontMultiplier: 0.04,
        };

        private margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 80};



        constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
            this.host = options.host;

            let svg = this.svg = d3.select(options.element)
                .append('svg')
                .classed('worksheet', true);
        }

        public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
            let width = options.viewport.width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
            let height = options.viewport.height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

            this.svg.attr({
                width: width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right,
                height: height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom
            });



            let parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;                       

            let xScale = d3.time.scale()
                .domain(this.data.map(function(d) { return parseDate(d.date); }))
                .range([0, width])

            let yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, d3.max(this.data, function(d) { return d.close; })])
                .range([height, 0]);        

            let xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xScale)
                .orient("bottom")
                .ticks(10)

            let yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yScale)
                .orient("left")
                .ticks(10)
                .innerTickSize(-width)
                .outerTickSize(10)
                .tickPadding(10)



            let worksheet = d3.select(".worksheet")
                .attr("width", width + this.margin.left + this.margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom);


            // remove exsisting axis and bar
            this.svg.selectAll('.axis').remove();
            this.svg.selectAll('.bar').remove();
            this.svg.selectAll('.chart').remove();


            let chart  = d3.select(".worksheet")
              .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")")
                .attr("class", "chart")

            chart.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis);


            chart.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)


            let line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) { console.log(parseDate(this.data.date)); return xScale(parseDate(this.data.date)); })
            .y(function(d) { return yScale(this.data.close); })
            .interpolate("linear")

            chart.append("path")
                .datum(this.data)
                .attr("class", "line")          
                .attr("d", <any> line)

        }

        public destroy(): void {
            //TODO: Perform any cleanup tasks here
        }
    }
}
```

[Power BI chart with axes but without line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkhK7.png)

Comment: Here is link to sandbox at CodePen: https://codepen.io/SuszonyDzik/pen/aBaJJQ

Comment: Please try now. At first I added code, that worked. Then I tried to clean it and there was a small time window when it didn't work. Now should be ok. Here is screenshot: http://ultimamailer.com/LineChart-CodePen.png

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. (Just blank)

Comment: @MarekJ Your CodePen link doesn't seem to show anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the code from

```
chart.append("path")
.datum(this.data)
.attr("class", "line")          
.attr("d", <any> line)
```

To

```
chart.append("path")
.datum(this.data)
.attr("class", "line") 
.attr("d", "M" + this.data.map((d)=> {
return xScale( parseDate(d.date)) + ',' + yScale(d.close);
}).join('L'))
```

And also from the below

```
let xScale = d3.time.scale()
.domain(this.data.map(function(d) { return parseDate(d.date); }))
.range([0, width])
```

to

```
let xScale = d3.time.scale() 
.domain(d3.extent(this.data,function(d) { return parseDate(d.date); }))
.range([0, width])
```

I have modified the code and worked. Please find the output.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYypI.png)